# Is there a way to get create label classes similar to symbology classes?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is there any way to get the same classes of label size as by the symbols? For example: I divided towns according to their population to 5 classes (as graduate symbology), and want to label each class by different size of fonts.

Answer (score 2):

To label each class by different size of fonts you may need to go to 
`Layer Properties > Labels > Text` and choose to override the `size` value, using an expression based on the *Population* field:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Your case statement/s are a bit malformed. I'm surprised they even work at all.  The correct statement should be `CASE 
     WHEN condition THEN result ELSE result2
     WHEN condition THEN result ELSE result2
     WHEN condition THEN result ELSE result2
     WHEN condition THEN result ELSE result2
END`

Only one `CASE and `END` keyword.

Comment: @Nathan W I've tested my solution both my solution in Valmiera an Dufour and it works well. Also, I've tested your statement and I have obtained "Expression is invalid".

Comment: Well lets just say mine is the correct way.